# Why is this property not bound to my directive's scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to write a directive that provides a custom button. The text within the button is provided to the directive through two attributes.

The button template:

```
<button>
  <div>{{digit}}</div>
  <div>{{letters}}</div>
</button>
```

The directive call:

```
<ws-dial digit="2" letters="ABC"></ws-dial>
```

The directive is defined like this:

```
angular.module ('MyApp').directive ('wsDial', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'ws-dial.html',
    scope: {
      digit: '=',
      letters: '='
    }
  });
```

However, only the content of the `digit` property is used; `letters` is empty as if it was undefined inside my directive.

I made an example on Codepen [here](http://codepen.io/piwinux/pen/OVOxXJ).

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You either have to change the binding type to @ for letters or wrap the ABC into single quotes. 
`letters="ABC"` looks for a variable named ABC in the scope and it does not find one so it is undefined (thus not displayed). You can do

```
<ws-dial digit="2" letters="'ABC'"></ws-dial>
```

which is like saying ABC is just text do not look for it in the scope.

Another way of doing it is changing the directive declaration as

```
  scope: {
    digit: '=',
    letters: '@'
  }
```

which says letters will be a string and not a variable in which case you would use the directive as you already have (without quotes)

Comment: Nope, not silly, it is actually a very common mistake and it is much more complicated how bindings work than it is first apparent. Note that using @ is one way binding, which might be safer to use if the directive is not supposed to mess with the bound value

Answer (score 3):

In Angularjs '=' is used for numbers where for strings ou have to use '@' 
here is your codepen code to understand it better    
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPjLLX

Answer (score 1):

The `scope: { x: '=' }` notation means that the `x` attribute in the HTML receives an Angular expression. The HTML `x="ABC"` means "give `x` the value of the *variable* `$scope.ABC`", which is of course `undefined`! On the other hand, `x="3"` means "give `x` the litteral value 3", which is OK. If you want the litteral string to be assigned to `x`, use quotes: `x="'ABC'"`.